# Parameterized ResourceDictionary - is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a control that's composed of a number of circling [`Ellipse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.ellipse) objects, like this (excerpt):

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100">

   <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"
               Width="8"
               Height="8"
               Fill="White" />
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="r0" Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="r0"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:1.5" />
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
   </Canvas>

   <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"
               Canvas.Top="10"
               Width="8"
               Height="8"
               Fill="White" />
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="r1" Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.05"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="r1"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:1.5" />
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
   </Canvas>

   <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"
               Canvas.Top="20"
               Width="8"
               Height="8"
               Fill="White" />
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="r2" Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.1"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="r2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:1.5" />
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
   </Canvas>

   <!-- ... -->

</Canvas>
```

Please note: All of the inner `Canvas`/`Ellipse` elements differ by:

1. `Ellipse.Canvas.Top`
2. `RotateTransform.Name`
3. `DoubleAnimation.BeginTime`

Now, I want to save me a lot of writing by creating a resource composed of:

- The inner `Canvas`
- The `Ellipse` therein
- The `RotateTransform` therein
- The `EventTrigger` therein
- The `DoubleAnimation` within the `Eventtrigger`

My final control would rather resemble something like this:

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
  {StaticResource myElem InnerTop=0, BeginTime="0:0:0.0"}
  {StaticResource myElem InnerTop=10, BeginTime="0:0:0.05"}
  {StaticResource myElem InnerTop=20, BeginTime="0:0:0.1"}
</Canvas>
```

Is something like this possible ***by utilizing Resources only***?

Or do I need to create a custom control, run by Code-Behind properties, to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I will describe two approaches to your issue using data templating or a `UserControl`.

### Items Control and Data Templates

You can create a small utility type that exposes the properties that you want to customize.

```
public class CirclingEllipseProperties
{
   public double Top { get; set; }

   public TimeSpan BeginTime { get; set; }
}
```

Create a data template for the circling ellipse item that binds these properties.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CirclingEllipseTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:CirclingEllipseProperties}">
   <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"
               Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
               Width="8"
               Height="8"
               Fill="White" />
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="r0" Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="{Binding BeginTime}"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="r0"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:1.5" />
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
   </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Create an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel`. Assign the data template as `ItemTemplate` and add an `x:Array` with `CirclingEllipseProperties` for each element as `ItemsSource`. You could even bind a collection of these elements from a view model or code-behind dynamically.

```
<ItemsControl Width="100"
              Height="100"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CirclingEllipseTemplate}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:CirclingEllipseProperties}">
         <local:CirclingEllipseProperties BeginTime="0:0:0" Top="0" />
         <local:CirclingEllipseProperties BeginTime="0:0:0.05" Top="10" />
         <local:CirclingEllipseProperties BeginTime="0:0:0.1" Top="20" />
      </x:Array>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</ItemsControl>
```

Of course, you can also create a style for the `ItemsControl`, if you want to reuse it.

```
<Style x:Key="CirclingEllipseItemsControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CirclingEllipseTemplate}" />
   <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource CirclingEllipseItemsControlStyle}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
      <!-- ...items source as above. -->
   </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</ItemsControl>
```

### Create a User Control

Create a custom `UserControl` that exposes properties for `Top` and `BeginTime`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApp.CirclingEllipseUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             Width="100"
             Height="100"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
   <Canvas>
      <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"
               Canvas.Top="{Binding Top, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CirclingEllipseUserControl}}}"
               Width="8"
               Height="8"
               Fill="White" />
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform x:Name="r0" Angle="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="{Binding BeginTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CirclingEllipseUserControl}}}"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="r0"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:1.5" />
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
   </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class CirclingEllipseUserControl : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty BeginTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "BeginTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(CirclingEllipseUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero));


   public static readonly DependencyProperty TopProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Top", typeof(double), typeof(CirclingEllipseUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

   public double Top
   {
      get => (double)GetValue(TopProperty);
      set => SetValue(TopProperty, value);
   }

   public TimeSpan BeginTime
   {
      get => (TimeSpan)GetValue(BeginTimeProperty);
      set => SetValue(BeginTimeProperty, value);
   }

   public CirclingEllipseUserControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

Add instances of the `CirclingEllipseUserControl` to your `Canvas` or create a `DataTemplate` for it like in the approach above to be able to dynamically bind items.

```
<Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
   <local:CirclingEllipseUserControl BeginTime="0:0:0" Top="0" />
   <local:CirclingEllipseUserControl BeginTime="0:0:0.05" Top="10" />
   <local:CirclingEllipseUserControl BeginTime="0:0:0.1" Top="20" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Great answer, very creative thinking! Thank you very much for your comprehensive and very informative answer! 